# How/what others think of you

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

In this sentence

> Don't worry about ( what / how ) others may think of you.

I think "**what**" is the answer, but I do not know why I cannot use "**how**" in this sentence.

Comment: You can use either form. They're equally idiomatic.

Comment: There's very little semantic difference between the two. It's essentially a free choice.

Comment: "Don't worry about how others may think of you" is a meaningful and entirely grammatical sentence, but I suspect that it is far less common in everyday use than "Don't worry about what others may think of you." A Google Books search turns up zero matches for the former and eleven matches for the latter, which is hardly overwhelming. But a GB search for the shorter phrase "worry about how others may think" yields just three matches (one verifiable), while a search for "worry about what others may think" draws ~120 verifiable matches along with a seemingly truncated number of unverifiable ones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"How" is associated with manner, means, circumstances.

- How can he think if he has a headache?
- How can he think this is right if he knows there is an error in the reasoning?

"What" concerns the object upon which the action is carried out.

- What do you explain by means of this diagram?
  I explain the numerical **relation** between A and B. (*what is being explained*)
- How do you explain the relation between A and B?
  I explain it (what) ***by means* of a diagram** (how).

Thus, as when you think something about someone, "something" is a grammatical object for the verb "think", it follows that "what" is the proper word.  In this case, the manner in which people think about someone else is not a usual concept, but you can find a telling example with a different sense of "think".

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Compilation_of_the_Statements_of_James_E/7IdMvwZkiWwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22how+did+you+think+about%22&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover)) How did you think about going to the newspaper office? What prompted you to do that?

Note that you can replace "how" with "what" and you do say a different thing.

- What did you think about going to the newspaper office?